# Is it possible to reduce size in shapefile to import to GEE

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine

I am trying to import a shapefile to Google Earth Engine but I keep getting: Layer error: Description length exceeds maximum, my file is the boundary for a country it´s 13.8 MB and I try to divided by two files (7.7 MB and 5.3 MB) then do a merge but still have the same error. Is there a way to downsize my files to be able to uploaded to GEE

```
//Bring in shapefiles used to filtering and to the clip composite to that area of interest
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection(table)
var fc2 = ee.FeatureCollection(table2)
var combinedFeatureCollection = fc.merge(fc2);
//#########################################################################################

//#########################################################
//Set Variable to the Landsat 8 Collection 1 Data
var l8dr = l8


//Wet Season Filters
//############################################################################
//Filtering Landsat 8 based on Dates, Bands, Spatial Area, Cloud, and Shadows
//Filter data based on dates
.filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.date('2014-05-15', '2014-10-30'),
        ee.Filter.date('2015-05-15', '2015-10-30'),
        ee.Filter.date('2016-05-15', '2016-10-30')))
    .select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4','B5','B6','B7','BQA'])
    //Filter data based on Spatial Area
    .filterBounds(combinedFeatureCollection)
    //Mask out cloud and shadows
    .map(cloud)
    .map(cloud_shadows)
//#############################################################################

/*
//Dry Season Filters
.filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.date('2017-03-01', '2017-06-30'), 
           ee.Filter.date('2018-03-01', '2018-06-30'),
           ee.Filter.date('2019-03-01', '2019-06-30')))
    .select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4','B5','B6','B7','BQA'])  
    //Filter data based on Spatial Area
    .filterBounds(combinedFeatureCollection)
    //Mask out cloud and shadows
    .map(cloud)
    .map(cloud_shadows)
*/
//###############################################################################

//Report the actual scenes in the collection that will be used to generate the Landsat 8 Composite
//median composite
var collection_merge = l8dr
print ('Composite collection Overview: ', collection_merge);

//#############################################################################
//Unpack QA BITS from BQA for applying Clouds and Shadows
function getQABits(image, start, end, newName) {
    // Compute the bits we need to extract.
    var pattern = 0;
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
       pattern += Math.pow(2, i);
    }
    // Return a single band image of the extracted QA bits, giving the band
    // a new name.
    return image.select([0], [newName])
                  .bitwiseAnd(pattern)
                  .rightShift(start);
}
//##############################################################################
//Apply QA bits for Clouds and update Mask
function cloud(image) {
  // Select the QA band.
  var QA = image.select(['BQA']);
  // Get the internal_cloud_algorithm_flag bit.
  var bits = getQABits(QA, 4,4, 'Cloud').eq(0);
  return image.updateMask(bits);
  // Return an image masking out cloudy areas.
}

//Apply bits for Clouds Shadows and update Mask
function cloud_shadows(image) {
  var QA = image.select(['BQA']);
  var bits = getQABits(QA, 7,8, 'Cloud Shadow Confidence').eq(1);
  return image.updateMask(bits);

}
//############################################################################
// Mosaic to the band-medians for the time series stack.
var median = collection_merge.median();
//#############################################################################

//############################################################################
//Print the number of images that are in the composite
var count = collection_merge.size();
print ('Number of images in the composite collection: ', count);

//############################################################################
//Clips the composite to the Area of Interest
var clipped_median = median.clipToCollection(combinedFeatureCollection);
//############################################################################

//############################################################################
// Set parameters and outputs for display and download

//Set L8 Bands for Display
var rgb_viz = {min:0, max:0.3, bands:['B7','B5','B2']};

//Assign variable for display and download
var med_export = clipped_median

//Set L8 Bands that will be downloaded
.select(['B2','B3','B4','B5','B6',"B7"]);

//Add Data to Viewer
Map.addLayer(med_export , rgb_viz, 'Mexico Landsat 8 Composite (Wet Season)');
//Map.addLayer(med_export , rgb_viz, 'Mexico Landsat 8 Composite (Dry Season)');
Map.addLayer(table3 , {color: 'FF0000'}, 'Extent');

// Export the image to match the original 
var wgs84_crs = 'EPSG:4326';
//#################################################################################

//#################################################################################
//Download data from GEE

Export.image.toDrive({
     
     // Landsat 8 Composite
     image: med_export.unmask(0),
  
    //Description of Composite of which your going to download 
    description: 'wet_seasonG',
    //description: 'Mexico Landsat 8 Composite (Dry Season)',
  
    //Location of where its going to download
    folder: 'GEE', // RENAME output folder accordingly
    //Set pixel size
    scale:30,
    //Max number of pixels it can handle to download
    maxPixels: 3784216672400,
    //Set area of interest
    region: combinedFeatureCollection,
    //Set your projection
    crs: wgs84_crs
    });
//###################################################################################

//End of Script
```

Comment: The only ways to reduce shapefile (`.shp`) size are to generalize (each vertex takes 16 bytes) or reduce feature count. The only ways to shrink dBase (`.dbf`) are to remove fields, replace string fields with shorter ones,  or reduce feature count.

Comment: You had a tag for ArcMap but make no mention of using that software so I removed it.

Comment: Have you tried radically downsizing, e.g. by deleting all features except one, or (if only one feature), deleting most of its vertices. Try to upload this test layer, to check if it is really the size of the file and not something else (e.g. number of vertices or attribute length).

Comment: The error is `Layer error: Description length exceeds maximum`. I do not know GEE and what is "Description" but could it be something that you have written to define the dataset?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense.  That error has nothing to do with the size of a shapefile or import, it's something being generated while trying to display a layer.

Can you post a link to the code you're working with a reproducible example of how you're generating that error.